# Querying Manage Metadata database in sahrepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, metadata

I need to get terms & term set information from MMS database for a custom application running on SQL. I want to know how bad it will be to execute a read query against SP MMS database and what can be other options to get terms information when using SQL?

Also I read on most of the places it says no direct queries against content database (except Technet), does that means we can run queries against MMS database and UPS databases?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, direct queries against SharePoint databases with the exception of Project Server tables and the Usage database are unsupported. There is a notation that Microsoft Support will ask you to cease any queries against a database if found to cause an impact; the issue is it is unlikely you'll be able to measure such an impact.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr

There are multiple methods to query the MMS data, such as REST, CSOM, and so forth. Which one you use depends on what is the most appropriate for your specific requirements.